# Stop computer displaying bank user name

Tags: google-chrome

I've clicked do not remember me on this computer and turned of my bank on sites I visit on home screen but computer still puts up my username when I type in bank home page how do I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) and obliterate "Autofill form data" and "Passwords" from the beginning of time:

[image]